# Я полный ноль в программировании и мой отец дал мне задание сделать аудиоплеер для Андройд. Что мне нужно изучить?

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

Мой срок - месяц, мне нужно за это время изучить язык до того уровня чтобы я смог написать приложение. Что мне следует изучить?

Comment: Рекомендую к быстрому изучению https://vk.com/wall-199535832_364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала надо изучить язык программирования JAVA, потом уже можно переходить к изучению разработки мобильных приложений.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос